# Apache is downloading perl files instead of showing them

Tags: linux, apache

I'm using apache 2.4.6 and cent-os 7.3
I don't know why but when I'm trying to display perl file my browser is trying to download it instead of showing it.
I have perl installed on my server and I can run perl files.

Comment: I saw an exact question about it but instead of perl there was PHP

Comment: You should move to close it *if* its similar to this question and its on Stack Overflow. If you can provide a link, then I'll cast a vote with you.

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/path/to/cgi-bin/" and that your scripts are in that folder.
If your scripts ends on .pl make sure to change the line
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi to AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and check that it is not commented out.

Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI --> needs to set in your virtual host

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. How to I set the follow syslinks on my virtual host?